# Python bcolz how to merge two ctables

Tags: python, pandas

i was playing around with the bcolz in memory compression examples from this [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Blosc/movielens-bench/blob/master/querying-ep14.ipynb)

So far i am really astonished by this library. And i think its a great tool for all of us that want to load bigger files into small memory (nice work  Francesc, if you are reading this!)

I wonder if anyone has some experience in joining two ctables like with pandas.merge() and how to do this time/memory effective.

Thanks for sharing your ideas :-)!

Comment: The bcolz come with iterators, so in doing something that can't be simply expressed for evaluate, you'll need to iterate the two inputs. Were you wanting the full range of behaviours of merge, or something more specific?

Comment: @mdurant,thanks for your reply :-). Best would be to have the same functional range as pd.merge. but i already like the idea of using iterators/generators. I will play around with this and try to combine it with simple MapReduce. If i come to significant improvements i will post here

Comment: This, which works lazily on iterators, may be the way to go - the output (also an interator) should then be piped back to a bcolz. http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.join

Comment: @mdurant: thats a good hint. I try it in line next time i have a nice usecase

Comment: FYI toolz.join is only streaming in the right argument.  I would probably pull off numpy chunks from the ctable as recarrays, merge them in memory, and then append them onto a target table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I GOT IT JUST IN TIME.. big thanks to @mdurant for the itertoolz!! here's some pseudo-code as the example I was using is SUPER ugly.

```
# here's generic pandas
df_new = pd.merge(df1,df2) 


# example with itertoolz and bcolz
from toolz.itertoolz import join as joinz
import bcolz

#convert them to ctables
zdf1 = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(df1)
zdf2 = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(df2)

#column 2 of df1 and column 1 of df2 were the columns to join on
merged = list(joinz(1,zdf1.iter(),0,zdf2.iter()))

# where new_dtypes are the dtypes of the fields you are using
# mine new_dtypes= '|S8,|S8,|S8,|S8,|S8'
zdf3 = bcolz.fromiter(((a[0]+a[1]) for a in merged), dtype = new_dtypes, count = len(merged))
```

obviously there are probably some smarter ways and this example isn't very specific , but it works and could serve as a base for someone to build it out more

## EDIT WITH EXAMPLE Oct 21, 7PM EST

```
#download movielens data files from http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/
#I'm using the 1M dataset
import pandas as pd
import time
from toolz.itertoolz import join as joinz
import bcolz

t0 = time()
dset = '/Path/To/Your/Data/'
udata = os.path.join(dset, 'users.dat') 
u_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv(udata,sep='::',names=u_cols)

rdata = os.path.join(dset, 'ratings.dat')
r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv(rdata, sep='::', names=r_cols)

print ("Time for parsing the data: %.2f" % (time()-t0,)) 
#Time for parsing the data: 4.72

t0=time()
users_ratings = pd.merge(users,ratings)
print ("Time for merging the data: %.2f" % (time()-t0,))
#Time for merging the data: 0.14

t0=time()
zratings = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(ratings)
zusers = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(users)
print ("Time for ctable conversion: %.2f" % (time()-t0,))
#Time for ctable conversion: 0.05

new_dtypes = ','.join([x[0].str for x in zusers.dtype.fields.values()][::-1] +[y[0].str for y in zratings.dtype.fields.values()][::-1])

#Do the merge with a list stored intermediately
t0 = time()
merged = list(joinz(0,zusers.iter(),0,zratings.iter()))
zuser_zrating1 = bcolz.fromiter(((a[0]+a[1]) for a in merged), dtype = new_dtypes, count = len(merged))
print ("Time for intermediate list bcolz merge: %.2f" % (time()-t0,))
#Time for intermediate list bcolz merge: 3.16

# Do the merge ONLY using iterators to limit memory consumption
t0 = time()
zuser_zrating2 = bcolz.fromiter(((a[0]+a[1]) for a in joinz(0,zusers.iter(),0,zratings.iter())) , dtype = new_dtypes, count = sum(1 for _ in joinz(0,zusers.iter(),0,zratings.iter())))
print ("Time for 2x iters of merged bcolz: %.2f" % (time()-t0,))
#Time for 2x iters of merged bcolz: 3.31
```

As you can see, the version I created is 15X slower than pandas, however by using only the iterators it will save A LOT of memory. Feel free to comment and/or expand on this. bcolz seems like a great package to build out.